# How to deal with bubbling events of different elements?

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

There are multiple controls in the ListViewItem, after I add the event proxy method to Textblock, It first calls the `ListView.ItemClick` event and then the `TextBlock.Tapped` event.

**However**, Have a feature that when a user clicks a `Textblock`, **it just needs to call the `Textblock.Tapped` event without calling the `ListView.ItemClick` event**, when the user clicks the control is not TextBlock, the `ListView.ItemClick` event is called

xaml:

```
<ListView ItemClick="ListView_ItemClick">
    <ListViewItem>
        <StackPanel>
            <Image/>
            <!-- other controls -->
            <TextBlock Tapped="TextBlock_Tapped"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </ListViewItem>
</ListView>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disable `ItemClick` event when the pointer enters the `TextBlock` and re-enable it when pointer exit the `ItemClick` event

In XAML

```
<ListView Name="MyListView" ItemClick="MyListView_ItemClick">
    <ListViewItem>
        <StackPanel>
            <Image/>
            <!-- other controls -->
            <TextBlock Tapped="TextBlock_Tapped"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </ListViewItem>
</ListView>
```

In Code behind

```
private void TextBlock_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
{

}

private void MyListView_ItemClick(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
{

}

private void TextBlock_PointerEntered(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MyListView.IsItemClickEnabled = false;
}

private void TextBlock_PointerExited(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MyListView.IsItemClickEnabled = true;
}
```